# How can I connect to SQL Server remotely?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my office there's a Windows XP computer with SQL Server Management Studio installed.

The DBA left the company. We are trying to know how he configured the system.

All computers connect to the router in the office are able to access the SQL Server engine using the IP address of the server computer. But we are not able to connect to the server from home.

I want to access the server from home only myself.

Can you share some information on where should I start and which configurations are involved?

By the way, I don't really want to use remote desktop or other tools to connect to the server computer. I just want to access to database engine only.

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you described is technically possible but you open up your database to all kinds of security risks.  Research VPN and remote desktop connection.  You can try something like Citrix or maybe [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/).  But you're not going to be able to connect to your database server outside your network the same way you would inside your network nor would you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at a VPN Server. You could open ports on your router, however a VPN would be way more secure.

Once setup your computer would appear as if it was located on the office network.

I think this question would've been better suited on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)